# What's the sequence for patching the WSO2-CARBON-PATCH-XXX-YYYY?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm evaluating the WSO2 Identity Server. Today I've received the email about the new path. I've no idea what the sequence for patching the WSO2-CARBON-PATCH-XXX-YYYY is. Should I patch by number order? I'm not sure if there is any prerequisite or not.

Could you please help to advise further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two more patches, You have to follow the order based on the patch number indicate by YYYY.

You can refer the README file inside the patch to know how to apply the patch.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can patch properly.